# PayPal website payments pro and ipn

Tags: paypal

I currently using website payments standard with PayPal and it works fine. I use a lot of the ipn functions.

I am looking to migrate to pro so I can control the checkout experience.

I was reading https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPWebsitePaymentsPro/

But cannot seem to tell if ipn will still work with the pro version.

If so how to I set item_name and such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes IPN still works with the PayPal Pro too . You will get the IPN for credit card payments in the same way as you get for PayPal transactions . For showing the item details you need to pass the line item details while submitting the transaction . You can refer the API docs here :

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoDirectPayment_API_Operation_NVP/

And below is a sample request :

```
NVP Request:
USER=XXXXXX&PWD=XXXXXX&SIGNATURE=XXXXXX2js3l1Kd48i&VERSION=109.0&METHOD=DoDirectPayment&PAYMENTACTION=Sale&IPADDRESS=192.168.0.1&AMT=20.00&CREDITCARDTYPE=Visa&ACCT=4916242305306840&EXPDATE=102020&CVV2=123&FIRSTNAME=John&LASTNAME=Test&STREET=12312 Port Grace Blvd&CITY=La Vista&STATE=NE&COUNTRYCODE=US&ZIP=68128&CURRENCYCODE=USD&L_NAME0=ProductA&L_DESC0=DescrA&L_AMT0=12.00&L_NUMBER0=AAAA&L_QTY0=1&L_NAME1=ProductB&L_DESC1=DESCB&L_AMT1=8.00&L_NUMBER1=BBB&L_QTY1=1&ITEMAMT=20.00

NVP Response:
TIMESTAMP=2015-04-10T23:03:55Z
CORRELATIONID=868df2e4ac78a
ACK=Success
VERSION=109.0
BUILD=16139311
AMT=20.00
CURRENCYCODE=USD
AVSCODE=X
CVV2MATCH=M
TRANSACTIONID=5EY755831A6318847
```

The IPN corresponding to it :

[image]